# Jenetics: how do I access evolution result (or statistics) at each step?

Tags: java, frameworks, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming, jenetics

I am working on an optimization engine based on the Jenetics framework ([link to jenetics.io](http://jenetics.io)). I have a evolution engine definition as follows:

```
final Thread engineStream = new Thread(() -> {
final MinMax<EvolutionResult<DoubleGene, Double>> best = MinMax.of();

_scannerEngine.stream()
    .limit(byPopulationConvergence(convergenceCriterion))
    .limit(result -> !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())                              
    .limit(maxGenerations)
    .peek(best).forEach(evolutionResult -> {
        waiting();
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.accept(evolutionResult, best.getMax());
        }
        final String generationCounter = String.valueOf(evolutionResult.getGeneration());
       _callingInstance.doOnAlgorithmCallback(new String("****** finished generation: " + generationCounter + " ****"));
    });
}

engineStream.start();
```

Currently, I am pushing at the end of one evolution cycle (one iteration through the population) a message to my UI via

```
peek(best).forEach(
    ...
    _callingInstance.doOnAlgorithmCallback(...)
)
```

What I would like to do is to push the current state of the evolution (ideally some statistics containing current fitness average, min, max, etc.) **after having executed each fitness step**, so the user can see the current state of the optimization process.

Any idea?

---

Final implementation based on Franz Wilhelmstötter's suggestions:

```
final Thread engineStream = new Thread(() -> {
    final MinMax<EvolutionResult<DoubleGene, Double>> best = MinMax.of();

    try {
        _scannerEngine.stream() //
        // stop stream if fitness average across the population is smaller than % of best fitness
        .limit(byFitnessConvergence(5, 20, convergence%)) //
        .limit(interrupted -> !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) //
        .limit(_geneticScanParameters.getMaxGenerationsLimit()) // maximum number of generations
        .peek(best) //
        .peek(_statistics) //
        .forEach(evolutionResult -> {
            waiting();
            if (callback != null) {
                MessageLogger.logError(getClass(), best.getMax().toString());
                if (_geneticScanParameters.getOptimizationStrategy() == Optimize.MAXIMUM) {
                    callback.accept(evolutionResult, best.getMax());
                } else if (_geneticScanParameters.getOptimizationStrategy() == Optimize.MINIMUM) {
                    callback.accept(evolutionResult, best.getMin());
                }
            }
            MessageLogger.log(getClass(), _statistics.toString());
            final String generationCounter = String.valueOf(evolutionResult.getGeneration());
            _callingInstance.doOnAlgorithmCallback(new String("****** finished generation: " + generationCounter + " ****"));
        });

        MessageLogger.log(getClass(), "\n" + _statistics.toString());
    } catch (final Exception ex) {
    MessageLogger.logError(getClass(), Thread.currentThread(), ex);
    }
    _callingInstance.doOnAlgorithmFinished();
});
engineStream.start();
_engineStream = engineStream;
```

Please note that I use a convention where "_variable" are class attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [EvolutionStatistics](http://jenetics.io/javadoc/jenetics/io/jenetics/engine/EvolutionStatistics.html%22EvolutionStatistics%22) class for this purpose.

```
final Engine<DoubleGene, Double> engine = ...
final EvolutionStatistics<Double, DoubleMomentStatistics> statistics =
    EvolutionStatistics.ofNumber();

final Phenotype<DoubleGene, Double> result = engine.stream()
    .limit(bySteadyFitness(7))
    .limit(100)
    .peek(statistics)
    .collect(toBestPhenotype());

System.println(statistics);
```

If you update the class in the `peek` method you will get some additional statistics.

Comment: Hi Franz, thanks for the help, but this is not what I intended. The code snipped you provided gives the evolution statistics at the _end_ of the optimization. I want to monitor the process at _each step_, ideally at each single setting of values of an individual. Maybe I should mention that I run the engine single threaded, between each call of the ftness function there are a couple of seconds.

Comment: Sorry, I mean you can do the same with the `EvolutionStatistics` as with the `MinMax` object: Update it in the `peek` method and call the `doOnAlgorithmCallback` method in the `Stream.forEach`.